# ArgumentException vs. ArgumentNullException?

Tags: c#, .net

I’m refactoring some code and adding a method which will replace a (soon-to-be) deprecated method.  The new method has the following signature:

```
FooResult Foo(FooArgs args) { ... }
```

The deprecated method contained a growing list of parameters.  These parameters are now properties on the `FooArgs` class.  The deprecated method has several guard conditions which checked for null values with the following structure:

```
if (parameter1 == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(“parameter1”);
if (parameter... == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(“parameter...”);
if (parameterN == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(“parameterN”);
```

Now that the parameters have been collapsed into the `FooArgs` class should I throw an **ArgumentNullException** for the individual properties of the `FooArgs` parameter:

```
if (args.Property1 == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(“args.Property1”);
if (args.Property... == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(“args.Property...”);
if (args.PropertyN == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(“args.PropertyN”);
```

Or to throw a more general **ArgumentException** for the **entire** `FooArgs` parameter:

```
if (args.Property1 == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(“Property1 cannot be null.”, “args”);
if (args.Property... == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(“Property... cannot be null.”, “args”);
if (args.PropertyN == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(“Property2 cannot be null.”, “args”);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did the Closers really read the question?

Comment: Not sure why this has been closed. Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. Anyway, I'd like to add this: if you have control of the `FooArgs` class, and _if_ the properties should never be null, you could delegate the checking to the class itself.

Comment: I've removed the words "best practice" from the title and the question itself in hopes of elimnating the concerns that closed it.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what code contracts are for in .Net 4.0? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx

Comment: have you considered a solution where parameter are valid and consistent objects with no nulls? example class may be ProcessStartInfo where you can set FileName to null and it will stil return empty string not null. This is some kind of null object pattern. i'm asking because this approach for more complicated objects may be inconvenient

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add a check for the args itself to be non-null. The ANE is not appropriate for individual components, so you need to use more general AE, like this:

```
if (args == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(“args”);
if (args.Property1 == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(“Property1 cannot be null.”, “args”);
if (args.Property... == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(“Property... cannot be null.”, “args”);
if (args.PropertyN == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(“Property2 cannot be null.”, “args”);
```

Comment: `ArgumentException` is more generic and should only really be used for invalid arguments. Whereas `ArgumentNullException` is specific to arguments that are passed in as null references where a null reference is invalid.

Comment: @Slade This is exactly correct: if `args` is null, ANE is thrown; if `args` is not null, but one of its components is null (which of course makes `args` invalid) the more general AE is thrown.

Answer (score 10):

While I agree completely with [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459782/65358)'s answer, you may also want to consider moving the validation for `FooArgs` into the `FooArgs` class itself.  If this class is designed specifically to move arguments around, it is likely not valid for it to have null proeprties, in which case, I would allow its constructor to do its validation.

Comment: While [dasblinkenlight](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8459782/99406)'s answer contained the explanation I was looking for, I'll definitely look into this approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it may be best to check for a null reference of the `FooArgs` parameter inside that method, and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if a null reference has been passed in. Then if other methods or sections of code use the parameters contained within the args class, they should be the ones to check this and throw exceptions as necessary. However, if your method that takes in the args class **is** the one to use all the arguments, then it would be better to check for valid parameters in that method, as you suggested.

Also, use `ArgumentNullException` only for arguments that are null references. If it's simply an invalid value (for example an empty string), then you should use the more generic `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of depends on your tooling and how you feel about your tooling (resharper, fxcops and the like).  Some static code analysis tools accept this:

```
throw new ArgumentNullException(“args.Property...”,"args");
```

and reject this

```
throw new ArgumentNullException(“args.Property...”,"args.Property");
```

So if you want to use the tooling, then assertions of null-hood against a parameter property must throw an ArgumentException

It's also valid to just make it up as you go along. What ever communicates the right message to the maintenance developer to help him pass the parameters correctly is the correct message.